# when a view such as TextView is partially out of screen it sizes changes to fit the screen. how can i disable that?

Tags: android, textview

i have a TextView in a RelativeLayout that sometimes is partially out of the screen. the problem is that insted of just being partially out of the screen it's sizes change so that the entire TextView still remains on the screen. i want to know how to disable that change.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Posting your XML code would help!

Comment: make the textview to wrap the content

Comment: i already made the textview to wrap the content. this is the XML     <TextView android:id="@+id/neighborImage" 
  android:drawableBottom ="@drawable/icon"
  android:text="Temple Bar"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="matrix"
 />